# Autoit Adobe aerender

Tags: command-line, command, adobe, autoit, after-effects

I am rendering an Adobe After Effects Project with Autoit and aerender,
I put this line of code in the console:

```
  aerender -project C:\aeProjects\projekt_1.aep -comp "Main" -output C:\aeProjects\output\asd.avi
```

Now how can I check if this proccess is done, so that I can resume safely other steps. 
At the moment I just put a sleep but that is not a good practice I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ProcessExists function to do this.

Here is a simple example with a timeout option:

```
MsgBox(64, "RunCmdWait", RunCmdWait("notepad.exe"))

Func RunCmdWait($sRuncmd, $iTimeout = 10000)
    Local $iPid = Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & $sRuncmd, @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE, 6)
    Local $hTimer = TimerInit() ; Begin the timer and store the handle in a variable.

    While 1
        Sleep(250)
        ;Returns 0 when the process is closed
        If ProcessExists($iPid) = 0 Then
            SetError(0)
            ExitLoop
        EndIf

        ;Returns 1 on time out error
        If TimerDiff($hTimer) >= $iTimeout Then
            SetError(1)
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
    WEnd

    Return @error
 EndFunc   ;==>RunCmdWait
```

Here is a example with StdoutRead if you need to read the output:

```
 MsgBox(64, "StdoutRead", GetStdoutRead("dir"))

 Func GetStdoutRead($sRuncmd)
     Local $iPid = Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & $sRuncmd, @ScriptDir, @SW_HIDE, 6)
     Local $sStdoutRead = ""
     While ProcessExists($iPid)
        $sStdoutRead &= StdoutRead($iPid)
     WEnd

    Return $sStdoutRead
EndFunc   ;==>GetStdoutRead
```